# Solve $x^{\prime\prime} + x^\prime - 2x = e^{2t}\sin(2t)$ using operator method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(D^2 + D - 2)x = e^{2t}\sin(2t) \Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{(D-1)(D+2)}e^{2t}\sin(2t) \Rightarrow x = e^{2t}\frac{1}{(D+1)(D+4)}\sin(2t)$

But here I'm stuck, I don't know what to do with $\frac{1}{(D-1)(D+2)}\sin(2t) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(t)=e^{2t}\frac{1}{(D+1)(D+4)}\sin(2t)$$
Expand the denominator:
$$f(t)=e^{2t}\frac{1}{D^2+5D+4}\sin(2t)$$
Now note that $D^2=-4$
$$f(t)=e^{2t}\frac{1}{5D}\sin(2t)$$
You also have that:
$$\frac{1}{D}\sin(2t)=\int \sin (2t)dt=-\frac 12 \cos (2t)$$
Finally:
$$\boxed {f(t)=-\frac 1{10}e^{2t}\cos(2t)}$$

---

You can also apply the equality you find on the web. It's going to take you more steps to get the answer I posted but it gives the same result.
$$f(t)=e^{2t}\frac{1}{(D+1)(D+4)}\sin(2t)$$
$$f(t)=e^{2t}\frac{(D-1)(D-4)}{(D^2-1)(D^2-16)}\sin(2t)$$
$$f(t)=e^{2t}\frac{(D-1)(D-4)}{(-5)(-20)}\sin(2t)$$
$$f(t)=e^{2t}\frac{-5D}{(5)(20)}\sin(2t)$$
$$f(t)=e^{2t}\frac{-1}{10}\cos(2t)$$

Comment: Why $D^2 = -4$?

Comment: But that is only when the exponential is even right? If I have for example $\frac{1}{D^3}\sin(2a)$ will it be $D^3 = -a^2$?

Comment: Right, I was searching and find out that $P(D^2)\sin(ax) = \sin(ax)P(-a^2)$, but that only applies when all the coefficients of the polynomial are even. In the problem we have $D^2+5D+4$, so it's not even and therefore we can't use it. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Yes, it is more clear now, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome @Mystery